# push_back invalidates pointers in objects when calling the destructor

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a `struct` that contains a pointer like this:

```cpp
struct S {
  S();
  ~S();

  int i;
  std::vector<int>* j;
};

S::S() {
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
}

S::~S() {
  if (j != 0) {
    cout << "Delete " << j << std::endl;
    delete j;
  }
}
```

I want to put an unknown number of `S` in a `std::vector` using `push_back()`. However, when the `vector` reallocates its memory to grow, it calls the destructor of `S` and invalidates the pointer `j`.

I understand why the example below segfaults, but I would like to know if there is a good way I do not know to manage this case.

In practice, I think I'm able to fix my issue by removing the destructor `~S` and `delete`'ing in `main()` before the destruction of the `vector` at the end of its scope. After all, the memory is allocated in `main()`, but I have the feeling that `S` should deal with its memory in its destructor.

```cpp
int main()
{
    cout << "Insert the first one" << std::endl;
        
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.push_back(S());
    v[0].j = new std::vector<int> {1,2,3};
    
    cout << "Insert a new one" << std::endl;
    
    v.push_back(S());
    v[1].j = new std::vector<int> {2,3,4};

    std::cout << (*(v[0].j))[1] << std::endl; // segfault
    std::cout << (*(v[1].j))[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Do you know what a deep copy is? Do you know how to write a copy constructor?

Comment: There is almost never a reason to have an owning pointer to `std::vector`.

Comment: Your class does not respect [the rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) which is causing the problems you are encountering.

Comment: *but I have the feeling that S should deal with its memory in its destructor* -- Don't blame the destructor -- the `S` class has incorrect copy semantics, already noted by the class not respecting the rule of 3.  But why look for this trouble when there is no need to?  Just declare a `std::vector<int> j;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`S` is not defining any copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators with which to copy/move `j` around.  When the `std::vector` in `main()` reallocates its inner array, any existing `S` objects in it get copied/moved around in memory.

`j` gets invalidated in your example, because `S` is not attempting to manage `j` at all.  For each `S` object in `main()`'s `std::vector`, when it is copied/moved, its `j` pointer gets shallow-copied into the new object, and when the old object is destroyed then the `std::vector` pointed to by `j` gets destroyed as well, leaving `j` in the new object dangling, which is why you get the segfault when accessing `j` later.

When a `class` or `struct` owns a pointer to a resource, it MUST implement the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) properly to copy/move that resource when itself is copied/moved.  In a nutshell, the rule states that if a `class`/`struct` needs to implement either a destructor, a copy/move constructor, or a copy/move assignment operator, it likely needs to implement all of them.  In your case, since you have a destructor that destroys `j`, you need to add the others to ensure that every `S` object has a valid `j` to destroy.

In your example, I would suggest NOT allocating the `std::vector` from outside of `S` at all.  Let `S` handle that allocation, outside code should merely fill `j` with values as needed.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
struct S {
  S();
  S(const S &);
  S(S &&);
  ~S();
  S& operator=(S);

  int get_i() const;
  void set_i(int);

  std::vector<int>& get_j();
  const std::vector<int>& get_j() const;
  void set_j(std::vector<int>);

private:
  int i;
  std::vector<int>* j;
};

S::S() {
  i = 0;
  j = new std::vector<int>;
}

S::S(const S &src) {
  i = src.i;
  j = new std::vector<int>(*(src.j));
}

S::S(S &&src) {
  i = src.i; src.i = 0;
  j = src.j; src.j = nullptr;
}

S::~S() {
  cout << "Delete " << j << std::endl;
  delete j;
}

S& S::operator=(S rhs) {
  S temp(std::move(rhs));
  std::swap(i, temp.i);
  std::swap(j, temp.j);
  return *this;
}

int S::get_i() const {
  return i;
}

void S::set_i(int new_value) {
  i = new_value;
}

std::vector<int>& S::get_j() {
  return *j;
}

const std::vector<int>& S::get_j() const {
  return *j;
}

void S::set_j(std::vector<int> new_value) {
  *j = std::move(new_value);
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    cout << "Insert the first one" << std::endl;
        
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.emplace_back();
    v[0].set_j({1,2,3});
    
    cout << "Insert a new one" << std::endl;
    
    v.emplace_back();
    v[1].set_j({2,3,4});

    std::cout << v[0].get_j()[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[1].get_j()[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, don't use `new`/`delete` manually at all, use `std::unique_ptr` instead, then you can remove the destructor completely (but not the copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators), eg:

```cpp
struct S {
  S();
  S(const S &);
  S(S &&);
  S& operator=(S);

  int get_i() const;
  void set_i(int);

  std::vector<int>& get_j();
  const std::vector<int>& get_j() const;
  void set_j(std::vector<int>);

private:
  int i;
  std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> j;
};

S::S() {
  i = 0;
  j = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>();
  // or, prior to C++14:
  // j.reset(new std::vector);
}

S::S(const S &src) {
  i = src.i;
  j = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(*(src.j));
  // or, prior to C++14:
  // j.reset(new std::vector<int>(*(src.j)));
}

S::S(S &&src) {
  i = src.i; src.i = 0;
  j = std::move(src.j);
}

S& S::operator=(S rhs) {
  S temp(std::move(rhs));
  std::swap(i, temp.i);
  std::swap(j, temp.j);
  return *this;
}

int S::get_i() const {
  return i;
}

void S::set_i(int new_value) {
  i = new_value;
}

std::vector<int>& S::get_j() {
  return *j;
}

const std::vector<int>& S::get_j() const {
  return *j;
}

void S::set_j(std::vector<int> new_value) {
  *j = std::move(new_value);
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    cout << "Insert the first one" << std::endl;
        
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.emplace_back();
    v[0].set_j({1,2,3});
    
    cout << "Insert a new one" << std::endl;
    
    v.emplace_back();
    v[1].set_j({2,3,4});

    std::cout << v[0].get_j()[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[1].get_j()[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, with that said, there is really no good reason to allocate `j` dynamically at all.  `std::vector` implements the Rule of 3/5/0 for itself, so you can get rid of the dynamic pointer in `S` and let the compiler manage the `std::vector` object for you, just like it does for the `std::vector` object in `main()`, eg:

```cpp
struct S {
  int i = 0;
  std::vector<int> j;
};
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    cout << "Insert the first one" << std::endl;
        
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.emplace_back();
    v[0].j = {1,2,3};
    
    cout << "Insert a new one" << std::endl;
    
    v.emplace_back();
    v[1].j = {2,3,4};

    std::cout << v[0].j[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[1].j[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This clarifies the situation.